# I want to print a character in a *.txt file using matlab (the keyboard input is number)

Tags: matlab, input, char, printf

```
fileID = fopen('nums.txt','w'); %opens a.txt file
s = input('s = '); %requests a number as input from the keyboard
a = char(s) %converts the number to character
fprintf(fileID,'%4.4f\n',a); %prints the character (not number) in a *.txt file
```

The purpose is to print a character in a *.txt file, which is written as number in advance. I type the number as input, and then I convert the number to the corresponding character.
Even though matlab returns me a = ! in the Command Window, the *.txt file include the number  (typed by keyboard) 33 (unconverted to the corresponding character, as it should be)

Looking forward to your generous help.

Comment: Perhaps consider using `'s'` as second argument in `input`, so the conversion with `char` is not needed; plus the input won't get evaluated. Then the output of `input` is exactly what has been entered by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is in the `fprintf()`: the `%f` tag means a floating point number whereas `a` appears to be a string. You need to use `%s` to write a string in `fprintf()`.

Let's say we type `33`, as you suggested.
According to your code, in the Command Window we'll have `a=!`, which is correct, but in the .txt file we'll have `33.0000` because the `fprintf()` intrinsically re-converts it back to numerical (floating point, to be precise) due to the `%f` tag.
By replacing your `fprintf()` with

```
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n',a); %prints the character (not number) in a *.txt file
```

the Command Window obviously will still display `a=!` but this time in the .txt file we'll have `!` as well.